# Methods of running with Elevated Privileges in a MOSS Publishing Site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

**I am wondering why the two methods listed below do not give the same security trimming.**

**Expected result:**  Both methods give full access to all content in the *current site collection*

**Actual result:**  Security trimming is occurring when using Method #1

- Method #2 works properly for retrieving content from other webs, but Method #1 does not.
- Both methods give access across webs in *Anonymous* mode, and both work for *site admin* accounts.
- The difference comes for *Hierarchy Managers*, *Approvers* and *Editors*.  Method #1 does not give admin access across webs.

**Method #1**

```
using (SystemOperation op = new SystemOperation())
{ 
    //Do an operation that requires retrieving across webs
}

public class SystemOperation : IDisposable
{
    private WindowsImpersonationContext ctx;

    public SystemOperation()
    {
        if (!WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().IsSystem)
        {
            ctx = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(System.IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool all)
    {
        if (ctx != null)
        {
            ctx.Undo();
        }
    }
}
```

**Method #2:**

```
   Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {
        //Do an operation that requires retrieving across webs
    });
```

Comment: Sorry I don't have an answer to your question, but I'm curious as to why you would use method 1? Also the code formatting seems to have screwed up in your question.

Comment: The reason you would need #1 is because RunWithElevatedPrivileges does not work in all instances, such as accessing the Profile Manager.

Comment: What about the SPSite.SystemAccount.UserToken (and new SPSite() using this token) method? How does that fit in?

Comment: bzlm - an example contrasting RWEP and SPUserToken. http://tinyurl.com/cdmvxe, The article is very pessimistic as according to MS RWEP "should be used with care. You should not expose direct, uncontrolled mechanisms for people with low privileges to circumvent the permissions granted to them".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RunWithElevatedPrivileges provides two separate privledges. First is that it elevates the Windows identity of the user to the AppPool account, the second is that it also elevates the identity to the SharePoint\System account which is a built in security account that provides full control (in a SharePoint sense). The internal SharePoint account is used when you construct your SP Objects (like SPSite).

So basically it will depend on how you build your code and when you instatiate your objects that affect how the privledges work out.